# The meaning of "full of them" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "full of them" in this context?

Moraine Lake, Canada

One of the most surprising things about this vast, remote lake is how accessible it is. It's a natural wonder in a landscape **full of them.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a natural wonder in a landscape full of **natural wonders.** Even though "them" could have been used and is frequently used in an ambiguous manner, this "them" immediately follows the subject.